# How to create a member variable of Arrow Atomic in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

[Arrow-fx](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-fx-coroutines/arrow.fx.coroutines/-atomic/) has a type Atomic which is similar to java AtomicRef but with an initial value, which means I don't need to check every time while accessing the atomic value whether it's null.

Here is a simple example

```
import arrow.fx.coroutines.*

suspend fun main() {
  val count = Atomic(0)

  (0 until 20_000).parTraverse {
    count.update(Int::inc)
  }
  println(count.get())
}
```

Now I would like to create a **class member variable** with this type, but since it's only possible to initialize within a suspend function I would like to know the possibility here.

Comment: One way would be using arrow AtomicRef https://arrow-kt.io/docs/1.1.0/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core.continuations/-atomic-ref/index.html#atomicref but it throws runtime exception if it's not initialized with a value.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make a "fake constructor" in the companion object.

```kotlin
public class Thingy private constructor(
  val count: Atomic<Int>
) {
  companion object {
    suspend fun invoke() = Thingy(Atomic(0))
  }
}
```

Now when you write `Thingy()`, you're actually calling the `invoke` function in `Thingy.Companion`. For that function there are no restrictions over suspending, so you can initialize `Atomic` as shown above.

Comment: Btw, making the constructor private or making the `invoke` function take no arguments is not part of the pattern, I just wrote those for the sake of a concrete example.

Comment: Note also that Arrow 1.2 is going to ship with a new `arrow-atomic` library which exposes a constructor without `suspend`. Unfortunately the only docs for now are [their implementation](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/main/arrow-libs/core/arrow-atomic/src/commonMain/kotlin/arrow/atomic/Atomic.kt), but this solves your problem in a forward-compatible way.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `suspend fun Thingy() = Thingy(Atomic(0))`, if you prefer to declare it somewhere other than in the `Companion`.